# Error file icon on vs 2017 on Windows 10 Enterprise Insder Preview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I opened a file, type something, save, error icon will appear. This error occurs when I upgraded my windows 10 to Enterprise Insider Preview. I restored to the old version, this error disappears. Today windows automatically updates, and this error reappears. Someone tell me how to fix this error, I do not want to resotore windows again[image]

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: No error message, only icon

Comment: I got this now after upgrading to W10 Fall Creators Update and VS2017 15.3.4 at the same time. I assumed the VS update was causing this issue, but according to this question, maybe Windows 10 Fall Creators Update is the guilty one.

Comment: You should file an issue with the relevant information in https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues

Comment: Or you could use Visual Studio's [Report a Problem feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 2):

According to this tweet, upgrading to VS2017 15.4 should fix the issue: https://twitter.com/davkean/status/921028563645505538

It's a known issue with Fall Creators Update and VS2017 15.3.4.